# Докирезация фронтенда

Tags: docker, frontend

Осваиваю докер. Докер файл находится в директории основного приложения. Есть еще подприложение, которое используется в приложении (микрофронтенд). У подприложения свои зависимости и соответственно эти зависимости нужно установить и собрать подпридожение отдельно. Не понимаю как мне изменить мой докер-файл. Изначально был докер файл в основном приложении и там было все просто.

```
FROM node:16.14  

WORKDIR /opt/

COPY . . 

RUN npm install 

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9102

ENTRYPOINT npm run dev
```